# Undefined DOM element javascript, while console.log gives it out

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm quite new in javascript and this problem is haunting me down since the very begining. When I get DOM element event behaves properly, but while I try to change anything (like class) it gives me "undefined is not a function".

I don't understand why, because in the same time console.log gives out

```
<div class="nav-about menu" id="nav-about"></div>
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-about menu" id="nav-about"></div>
```

JS

```
var link_one = document.getElementById("nav-about");

link_one.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(this);
    this.addClass('special');
}, false);
```

I couldn't find answer to that anywhere. Yes jquery to addClass is included in head tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no `addClass` property on `this`, so it's `undefined`.

You could add the class on `this.classList`.

```
var link_one = document.getElementById("nav-about");

link_one.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.add('special');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(this).addClass('special');
```

because you want to use jquery library, to use jquery library is like calling a function doSomething(this), but instead use $ as the function name